# how to superimpose a python df heatmap over an existing image without distortion

Tags: python, dataframe, resize, heatmap, superimpose

I have an existing image, from where I know the pixel size. And I know the location of my "source" (the orange cross in the blueprint) in x,y pixel coordinates using Paint. I calculate the source strength based on distance to source and drop this in a dataframe of which I make a heatmap. However the location of the source after overlaying both images is off in both x and y direction (to high and to the right) and as well the source strength pattern should be circular which is not the case.

How can I avoid the heatmap getting distorted and have the source in the original image match with the hotspot in the heatmap?

code I used:

```
width, height = Image.open(image_path1).size

tmp_strengths = []
# location of source(s) in pixel values:
xs = [934]
ys = [710]
sourcestrength = [10000]

my_dpi=96
plt.figure(figsize=(width/my_dpi, height/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

# create 2D array and fill it up with "1" values - value is unimportant at this point:
x = np.full((width, height), 1)

for i in range(len(x[0])):
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        # for z sources do:
        for z in range(len(xs)):
            #source strength = source strength - distance²
            strength = sourcestrength[z] - (math.sqrt(((ys[z]-j)**2)+((xs[z]-i)**2)))**2
            if strength < 0:
                strength = 0
                
            tmp_strengths.append(strength)
        
        x[j][i] = sum(tmp_strengths)
        
        # clean the tmp strength list again for the next i/j pairs
        tmp_strengths = []     
        

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
p1 = sns.heatmap(df, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, cbar=False, cmap = sns.cm.rocket_r)
p1.figure.savefig(heatmap_path,bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=my_dpi)

img = Image.open(heatmap_path)
newsize = (width, height)
img = img.resize(newsize)
img.save(str(heatmap_path).replace('.jpg','_2.jpg'))

background = Image.open(image_path1)
overlay = Image.open(image_path2)

background = background.convert("RGBA")
overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")

new_img = Image.blend(background, overlay, 0.5)
new_img.save(r"C:\Superimposed.png","PNG")
```

Keeping the color bar makes the distortion effect less, but then of course the overlap of the heatmap itself with the original image doesn't match anymore.

Even though I used plt.figure(figsize=(width/my_dpi, height/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi) I still had to resize the image afterwards because the created image (1162x921pixels) did not match the pixel size of the original image (1500x1220pixels).

[superposed images with color bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lOnB.png)

[superposed images without color bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6DBj.png)

Any ideas would be welcome.